# Differences between 2 java projects in Intelij IDEA? - Cannot refresh Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, plugins, gradlew

I have 2 separate `Java` Projects that I am able to both open in `Intelij`.

For one project I cannot refresh gradle -

```
"No such property - GradleVersion for class: JetGradlePlugin"
```

I also get `"cannot find declaration to go to"` when I click on a java class/method. All the java classes are shown with a `".java"` on the end in the Project View.

The other project does not have any issues at all.

I have ran `"clean"` and `"install"` for both - what could be the issue?

Note - I am running using Gradle wrapper and Java 8 for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like are using an old IntelliJ IDEA version (2017.x?) and the recent Gradle version (5.x?). This will not work, unfortunately.

You either need to downgrade to Gradle 4.10.3 or update to the current IntelliJ IDEA release to get the support for the most recent Gradle versions.

Your projects are probably using different Gradle versions via the Gradle wrapper, make sure the same version is used for the project that doesn't work.

[Related issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-206600).